# gradle Task :incrementVersion FAILED

Tags: gradle

I run Java Spring Boot project, and having this message:  `Task :incrementVersion FAILED`

Gradle 6.3, java 14.0.2

How can I fix it?

---------- Follows my build log:  --------------------

```
14:57:25: Executing 'build'...

> Task :openApiGenerate_api
Multiple schemas found in the OAS 'content' section, returning only the first one (application/pdf)
Multiple schemas found in the OAS 'content' section, returning only the first one (application/pdf)
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/total. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmTotalGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/{id}. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmIdGet
Empty operationId found for path: patch /claimissuefsm/{id}. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmIdPatch
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/{id}/pos. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmIdPosGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/{id}/export. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmIdExportGet
Multiple schemas found in the OAS 'content' section, returning only the first one (application/pdf)
Multiple schemas found in the OAS 'content' section, returning only the first one (application/pdf)
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/{id}/checklist. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmIdChecklistGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/{id}/fsmDocsChecks. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmIdFsmDocsChecksGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/fsmChecksStatuses. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmFsmChecksStatusesGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnshipmentfsm. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnshipmentfsmGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: patch /ttnshipmentfsm/{id}. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnshipmentfsmIdPatch
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnshipmentfsm/{id}/pos. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnshipmentfsmIdPosGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnshipmentfsm/{id}/export. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnshipmentfsmIdExportGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnshipmentfsm/{id}/fsmDocsChecks. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnshipmentfsmIdFsmDocsChecksGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnshipmentreturnfsm. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnshipmentreturnfsmGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: post /ttnshipmentreturnfsm. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnshipmentreturnfsmPost
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnshipmentreturnfsm/{id}/pos. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnshipmentreturnfsmIdPosGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnshipmentreturnfsm/{id}/export. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnshipmentreturnfsmIdExportGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnissuefsm. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnissuefsmGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: post /ttnissuefsm. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnissuefsmPost
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnissuefsm/{id}/pos. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnissuefsmIdPosGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnissuefsm/{id}/export. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnissuefsmIdExportGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnissuereturnfsm. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnissuereturnfsmGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: post /ttnissuereturnfsm. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnissuereturnfsmPost
Empty operationId found for path: post /ttnissuereturnfsm/ticket. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnissuereturnfsmTicketPost
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnissuereturnfsm/{id}/pos. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnissuereturnfsmIdPosGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: get /ttnissuereturnfsm/{id}/export. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: ttnissuereturnfsmIdExportGet
Empty operationId found for path: patch /fsmDocsChecks/{id}. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: fsmDocsChecksIdPatch
################################################################################
# Thanks for using OpenAPI Generator.                                          #
# Please consider donation to help us maintain this project ?                 #
# https://opencollective.com/openapi_generator/donate                          #
################################################################################
Successfully generated code to C:\java\Project\lk-fsm\build/generated/sources/openapi

> Task :openApiGenerate_api_v2
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: ClaimIssueCheckList
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
More than one inline schema specified in allOf:. Only the first one is recognized. All others are ignored.
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
More than one inline schema specified in allOf:. Only the first one is recognized. All others are ignored.
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: BalanceFsm_allOf
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/claimChecksComplete/{id}. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmClaimChecksCompleteIdGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: ClaimIssueCheckList
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/claimChecksInWork/{id}. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmClaimChecksInWorkIdGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/claimsComplete. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmClaimsCompleteGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
More than one inline schema specified in allOf:. Only the first one is recognized. All others are ignored.
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/claimsInWork. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmClaimsInWorkGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
More than one inline schema specified in allOf:. Only the first one is recognized. All others are ignored.
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/inWork/{id}. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmInWorkIdGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/complete/{id}. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmCompleteIdGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/complete/{id}/ttn. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmCompleteIdTtnGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/ttn/{id}/pos. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmTtnIdPosGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/balanceFsm/{id}. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmBalanceFsmIdGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: BalanceFsm_allOf
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/balanceFsm/{id}/pos. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmBalanceFsmIdPosGet
allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: PaginatedHeader
Empty operationId found for path: get /claimissuefsm/claimStatuses. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: claimissuefsmClaimStatusesGet
Empty operationId found for path: get /dashboard/quality-assurance/fsm. Renamed to auto-generated operationId: dashboardQualityAssuranceFsmGet
################################################################################
# Thanks for using OpenAPI Generator.                                          #
# Please consider donation to help us maintain this project ?                 #
# https://opencollective.com/openapi_generator/donate                          #
################################################################################
Successfully generated code to C:\java\Project\lk-fsm\build/generated/sources/openapi

> Task :incrementVersion FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
  Script 'C:\java\Project\lk-fsm\build-ci.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':incrementVersion'.
> Could not get unknown property 'buildNumber' for task ':incrementVersion' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

* Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

BUILD FAILED in 5s
14:57:31: Execution finished 'build'.
```

Comment: Please provide a sample Gradle build file.

Comment: For the safety of myself and others, please edit this post to include the contents of the Gradle build file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the following lines that did not perform:
I commented them to build project.

```groovy
task incrementVersion {
    doLast {
      //  buildNumber = buildNumber.toInteger() + 1
     //   version = "${version}.${buildNumber}"
      //  ant.propertyfile(file: "gradle.properties") {
     //       entry(key: "buildNumber", value: buildNumber)
      //  }
    }
}
```